# Cannot update the text in text file using fstream

Tags: c++, text-files, file-handling

I am trying to decrement the value of a number stored in a text file as shown:

```
fstream countfile;
countfile.open("adminsongcount.txt");
countfile >> songcount;
songcount--;
countfile << songcount;
countfile.close();
```

Clearly, the count should reduce by 1, say from 4 to 3, but it does not. On opening adminsongcount.txt I still get the value of 4.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you check if the file opened or not?

Comment: Simultaneously reading and writing a file is tricky. Most of the time it is much less difficult to open for reading, read in the whole file, close the file, modify the file contents in memory, open the file for writing, and rewrite the whole file. Or read from one file write to a temp file and replace the original with the temp after you are finished.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Yes I have, though I did not include that part here. It had opened with no issues.

Comment: @AtharvaRaykar Post a [MCVE] or nothing is considered to be happen with your code.

Answer (score -1):

If adminsongcount.txt originally consisted of a single character `'4'`, after running this code it would have two characters: `'4'` followed by `'3'`. If you repeat the same read, you'll get the `'4'` again.

To fix this, the code should seek to the beginning of the file before writing:

```
countfile.seekp(0);
```

This sets the **put** pointer (hence the 'p' at the end of the name) to be beginning of the file.

Comment: Or simply use the [`ios_base::open_mode::trunc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) flag when opening the file. I always get hiccups when seeing people using `seekp()` `tellg()` operations.

Comment: @user9212993 -- that's a good thought, but it doesn't work here, because it simply truncates the file, so the initial read fails and the file ends up empty. It would work if the code closed the file after the read and reopened it for the write.

Comment: Yeah, it's generally better to split up read/write operations using distinct `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` streams rather than `std::fstream`.

Comment: Proposed solution fails if number of digits decreases after decrementing.

Comment: Depending on how the file is written, the read may hit EOF and make the write fail. The 3 might not get written to the file.

Comment: @user4581301 -- yes, if the read fails for any reason (including the text file not being in the assumed format), the write will also fail. But that's not the problem in the question. Certainly, a more robust solution would have to address that.

Comment: @zett42 -- one problem at a time! <g> This fixes the immediate issue.